# Is this a proper way to prove simple geometrical result?

Tags: geometry, fake-proofs

I found this on Quora :

[image]

Is there anything wrong in the steps illustrated ?

Comment: Why do you think so?

Comment: basically the same triangle has been proven congruent to itself.Is this a proper way to proceed?

Comment: @user3365247 Just like $$1=1$$

Comment: At first I was looking at the wrong angle in step 3. I see now that they were talking about $\angle ABC$ being congruent to itself.

Comment: @user3365247 Maybe saying "congruent to itself" is hiding the trick that it's actually *congruent to its reflection across the vertical axis*. In that process, the two angles in question get overlaid, and it becomes clear they're congruent. Subtle difference, maybe :)

Comment: @rschwieb: Why don't you write an answer a bit more elaborately? It will be more good for the OP.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong in the steps illustrated.